# Evitar multiplicidad en filas duplicadas en SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2017

Espero puedan apoyarme para encontrar una solución al siguiente problema:

Tengo una base de datos en **SQL Server 2017** con tablas relacionadas por medio de tablas intermedias, ejemplo:

[image: Estructura de la base de datos]

Para realizar la consulta utilizo `LEFT JOIN` a varias tablas obteniendo por lo mismo resultados duplicados como los observan abajo:

```
1 con A1
2 con A2
y aqui se repiten en otro orden 
1 con A2
2 con A1
```

A pesar que son diferentes por logica sabemos que solo se puede remplazar un dispositivo por otro, lo que requiero es ayuda para poder mostrar unicamente una sola combinación en este caso que el resultado de la consulta sea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto sucede a causa de que a la hora de crear un ticket los usuarios no usan 1 ticket para un dispositivo si no que usan un ticket para realizar varios remplazos y no puedo evitarlo.

Agradezco de antemano su apoyo con mi consulta.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes Rock! Cuál es la consulta con que tienes problemas?

Comment: La consulta está diseñada dentro de un programa de control de tickets, que me permite hacer reportes y modificar hasta cierto punto el codigo SQL, pero al realizar la consulta me entrega valores repetidos como lo mencione en las imagenes, como ligan dos o mas dispositivos a un ticket entonces se repite el numero de veces el dispositivo de remplazo en la base de datos, lamentablemente no puedo extraer el codigo para mostrarlo, pero quisiera tener la noción del porque esta pasando eso y ver la manera de corregirlo con alguna clausula, ejemplo, si ya aparecio en T_Remplazo que no se repita.

Comment: Pero, he buscado en internet, algun problema similar pero no he encontrado de donde basarme. Agradezco su apoyo!

Comment: El problema principal es que si ligaron 3 dispositivos y 3 remplazos al mismo ticket me aparecen 9 registros: 1 con A1, 2 con A2, 3 con A3, luego 1 con A3, 2 con A1, etc... lo que intento es evitar porque no importa el orden simplemente que en el caso que sean 3 dispositivos, me resuelva 3 registro de remplazo diferente. No se si me doy a entender :/

Comment: El pivote siempre es el numero de ticket entonces me aparece 9 veces el ticket numero 500 por ejemplo pero cada uno es una combinacion diferente. Pero a veces ligan 2 dispositivos y solo 1 reemplazo, entonces es necesario solo tomar en cuenta el remplazo sin importar que dispositivo de los dos sea mostrado, pero en ese caso solo apareceria 1 registro en la consulta.

Comment: Creo que tu consulta, básicamente, debería ser así `select t1.*, t2.*, t3.* from tabla1 t1 inner join tablarelacion1 tr1 on t1.id=tr1.id_dispositivo inner join tabla2 t2 on tr1.id_ticket=t2.id inner join tablarelacion2 tr2 on t2.id=tr2.id_ticket inner join tabla3 t3 on tr2.id_remplazo=tr3.id`. Sin ver tu consulta ni tus datos no tengo cómo asegurar que esto funcione. Creo que tu problema es que alguno de tus joins no está correcto, por eso multiplica la información. Pero nuevamente, sin tu consulta real ni datos reales, yo no puedo ayudarte más.